# Why isn't .htaccess file being edited?

Tags: php, .htaccess, xampp, wamp

On my website, I have image uploading input field in one of the forms, and in general when I try to upload an image, everything works fine, but in some cases an error occurs in a file processing the form input. When I var_dump $_FILES array, I can observe that all elements of the array except name are empty.

I've noticed that it depends on a file size which is being uploaded. So I decided to edit .htaccess file to increase maximum possible value of uploaded image. **.htaccess file is placed in the root directory of my project**, I'm using XAMPP.

I wrote these lines in .htaccess:

```
php_value file_uploads = On
php_value post_max_size = 100000M
php_value upload_max_filesize = 100000M
<Directory />
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

But it doesn't seem to work. The problem still occurs when I upload a bigger image.

**What am I doing wrong? How can I make .htaccess work?**

**UPD 0:** I made some changes to the post

Comment: "I wrote these lines in .htaccess:" - if you wrote those lines in `.htaccess` then it would seem `.htaccess` overrides are not enabled since a `<Directory>` directive is not permitted here and will "break" your server (500 error).

Comment: @MrWhite i didn't get 500 error. I indeed wrote those lines in .htaccess.

Comment: @MrWhite  But in VS code .htaccess was saved with name .htaccess.bat. It shouldn't have .bat extension, right?

Comment: I've removed .bat and now the server produces the 500 error

Comment: Remove the `<Directory>` block - that is not valid in `.htaccess` (nor is it needed).

Comment: @MrWhite "a <Directory> directive is not permitted here and will "break" your server (500 error)." I looked through different tutorials and <Directory> was used there. It's deprecated now, or it can olny be used in some specific cases or what?

Comment: @MrWhite "Remove the <Directory> block - that is not valid in .htaccess" hmm. Ok maybe I got something wrong

Comment: `<Directory>` has _never_ been permitted in `.htaccess` - it makes no sense here. It is a server-only directive. The `.htaccess` file itself is the equivalent of a `<Directory>` container.

Comment: I've removed it, but I still get the 500 error...

Comment: I cleared .htaccess file and the error stopped occuring. When I filled it with the same content it occured again

Comment: I've tried to remove "php_value" before each of the parameters, tried to delete parameter one by one, but if there's anything at all in .htaccess, the error is initiated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> php_value file_uploads = On
> php_value post_max_size = 100000M
> php_value upload_max_filesize = 100000M
> <Directory />
>     AllowOverride All
> </Directory>
> ```

The `<Directory>` container is not valid inside `.htaccess` files and nor is it required here. The `.htaccess` file itself is effectively the `<Directory>` container.

Also, the syntax for setting the PHP config vars is incorrect, there should be no `=` here. For example:

```
php_flag file_uploads On
php_value post_max_size 100000M
php_value upload_max_filesize 100000M
```

Since `file_uploads` is a boolean, you should really use `php_flag`, instead of `php_value` to set this.

Also, whether this works at all is dependent on how PHP is installed. This is valid only if PHP is installed as an Apache module (ie. mod_php).

Comment: You're welcome. Actually, since `file_uploads` is a _boolean_, you should really be using `php_flag` to set this. I've updated my answer.